# How to insert data using user role in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to insert data by user role
Here is my controller

```
public function getWorks($class_id,Request $request)
    {
            @if(Auth::user()->role=="Teacher")
            else if($validator->fails())
            {
                $works = new assainments();
                $works -> title = $text;
                //$works -> file = $fileName;
                $works -> class_id = $class_id;
                $works -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $works -> save();

            }
            @endif
       }
```

I can't use here `@if(Auth::user()->role=="Teacher")`. How can i use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are doing something wrong i think so far. Here are probability answer:**

```
public function getWorks($class_id,Request $request)
{
      if(Auth::user()->role=="Teacher")
      {
         // do validation 
         // ....
         // ....

         if( !$validator->fails() )
         {
             $works = new assainments();
             $works -> title = $text;
             //$works -> file = $fileName;
             $works -> class_id = $class_id;
             $works -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
             $works -> save();

         }
      }
      else
      {
         // do return false
         return redirect()->back();
      }
 }
```